# formal definition of tensor in theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to make char-rnn which predicts the next character regarding previous characters with Theano.

So, there exists 4 notable tensors(or matrices).

> x: inputs shaped [timelength, inputsize]
>
> h: hidden states shaped [timelength, hiddensize]
>
> y: outputs shaped [timelength, inputsize]
>
> t: target values shaped [timelength-1, inputsize]

here, target value tensor t is clearly defined as formally:

> t[i, j] := x[i+1, j]
> but how to define t using above definition?

```
x = T.matrix(name="x")
t = ? # t[i] := x[i+1] but how to define it in theano?
```

ps. I have researched about nnet.conv2d of theano but had no luck

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on RNN?

Comment: I can implement RNN and its optimizer without any frameworks

Answer (score 0):

The original sequence is a vector of integers, coding characters. This is transformed into a one-hot encoding, giving inputs. The one-hot encoding of a character with index 5 is a vector where the 5th element is 1 and the rest are zeros. It looks like you're setting up targets to also use a one-hot encoding. This can be done, but isn't really necessary. You can just use the original integer encoding, in which case `t` will be a vector, not a matrix. The length should be `timelength`, not `timelength-1`.

The corresponding theano definition would be:

```
t = ivector(name="t") # for 32-bit integer
t = lvector(name="t") # for 64-bit integer
```

You should use whatever integer type you use for indexing, since the target will be used as an index into the outputs (`y`) when you compute the cross-entropy loss.

char-rnn processes consecutive blocks of a sequence. Say the original sequence of character-encoding integers is called `chars`. The current position in the sequence is `p`. The block length is `timelength`. For the current block, the inputs `x` contain the one-hot encoding of `chars[p : p + timelength]`. The targets `t` contain `chars[p + 1 : p + timelength + 1]`. This way, each target is one time step ahead of the input.

The original char-rnn code [here](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086) is fairly straightforward. It uses numpy and not theano, and the way it's written will be slightly different. But, it's very useful for understanding the concepts.

Comment: here exists some misunderstandings. since it's a prediction problem, the network for a timeslice should output x_t+1 for given input x_t. this makes t not required as input. it's defined. if I call calc_rnn_loss("abc") - note target value is not given, it should be able to calculate the loss.
I have no difficulty to understand RNN. it's clearly a theano question.